# How to load in a webpage and then click on an element in that webpage?

Tags: javascript, html

I wand to make a 'Google Searcher' that loads Google as an element of a webpage, inputs my search term and then presses search, i'm not sure if I am on the right path here but this is all I have:

```
<div> 
    <object type="text/html" data="http://www.google.co.nz/" width="800px" height="600px" style="overflow:auto;border:5px ridge blue">
    </object>
</div>
```

If you cant help with my original question could you please explain why that isn't working with Google?

Comment: You could just load the search result page like this:  https://www.google.com.au/search?q=test

Comment: This is against google's terms of service, you aren not supposed to programatically put queries to their service via a bot. What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this. It's against Google's [ToS](https://www.google.ca/cse/docs/tos.html):

> **1.4 Appropriate Conduct.**
>   You shall not, and shall not allow any third party to: [..] (i) directly or indirectly generate queries, or impressions of or clicks on Results, through any automated, deceptive, fraudulent or other invalid means (including, but not limited to, click spam, robots, macro programs, and Internet agents);

Why not just set up a [custom search](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/)?